# Visual studio code is shows gitlens always, what setting does cause this ?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, sourcegraph

Hi I am using Visual Studio code for JavaScript project, but suddently it started showing gitlens layout on left side of every file i open, i tried all possibilities, uninstall git related extensions and restarted VSCode, but it is still showing gitlens layout on left side as shown in screenshot it is annoying for development, can you please help what settings needs to be changed to get rid of this gitlens. 
[image]

Comment: This seems like a VSCode issue, not a Sourcegraph issue? (We're unaffiliated with the GitLens extension.)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you have the "File Blame Annotations" activated.

Try searching for the command "Toggle File Blame Annotations" and see if that makes that view go away.
Check also the settings for `gitlens.blame`.

Answer (score 0):

@Vonc you are right , below two setting changes worked for me thank you so much.
gitlens.currentLine.enabled: false, scm.blame.file: false